# Calculate next 3 prime numbers given an int in Haskell

Tags: haskell, time-complexity, prime-factoring

I am trying to write a function in Haskell that allows me to calculate the next 3 prime numbers, given a Intenger N and store the three prime numbers in a sorted list.

The challenge is to do it without import any external module.

Behavior of the function:

*nextPrimes 75 = [79,83,89]

*nextPrimes 64 = [67,71,73]

it should calculate the next 3 prime numbers of an N with 10-digit numbers in less than 2 minutes.

`nextPrimes :: Int -> [Int]
nextPrimes n`

Comment: What algorithm do you want to use for that?

Comment: I'd approach this in Haskell by first generating an infinite list of primes. Then search over this list until you get to the appropriate place, and take the next three primes from the list.

Answer (score 0):

sorry... but I could not resist...

```
nextPrimes :: Int -> [Int]
nextPrimes n = let sq    = fromIntegral . ceiling . sqrt $ fromIntegral n
                   pri k = (k,and [ k`mod`x/=0 | x <- [2..sq]])
               in  take 3 . map fst . filter snd $ map pri [n..]
```

This works almost instantly, even when we have to count up all the way until *sqrt n*:

```
λ> nextPrimes 295084709089
[295084709159,295084709209,295084709273]
```

Comment: that's amazing, thanks so much, appreciate it @oo_miguel

Comment: @DavidePollcino: Glad to help. So you can accept and vote up this answer now :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Oh, I was not aware of that.